# I need a good substitute for applesauce in a gumdrop recipe

Tags: candy

I need applesauce for a gumdrop recipe but I am out of it. what can i use as a substitute? I have seen people saying oil, but what kind? And just the same amount as applesauce, or what?

Comment: Please include or link to the recipe.

Comment: Gumdrop? As in the candy? Can you please be more specific by including your full recipe?

Answer (score 1):

When substituting applesauce for oil in baking, it is a 1:1 ratio. 1/4 cup applesauce for 1/4 cup oil (except for cookies).

The rationale behind using applesauce as an oil replacement is that applesauce is high in pectin, and pectin can form a film around individual grains of flour, just like oil does.

In general purée of any other high-pectin fruit should work such as banana. Basically fruit high in pectin and no watery.

As for what kind of oil, most cooking oils should work. I tend to use canola oil opposed to almond, grape or olive. The reason is the flavors of these oils, to me, tend to alter the flavor too much for my liking.

Comment: Hm. "Gumdrop" makes me think of candy, not cookies. And apart from baking, I don't think those are interchangeable at all. Definitively no downvote, though, because OP didn't clarify.